# re-tagging multi-arch docker image

Tags: docker, multiarch

I'm looking for a way to re-tag existing image under different name (for example we release version x.y.z and we would like to tag is as `latests` as well). Currently I would do:

```
docker pull docker/my-app:123
docker tag docker/my-app:123 docker/my-app:latest
docker push docker/my-app:latest
```

It works just fine with regular images but it breaks with multi-arch images and only architecture of my current machine is tagged/pushed. I'm aware that I could add `latest` tag to buildx (it allows multiple `--tag` parameters) but we also have case where we have `nightly` build and for (test) deployment purposes we tag them with more static tag (with date most of the time) and in this case `buildx` multiple tag approach breaks.

(I know there are several similar questions but they as about tagging images and pushing to different repositories, and quite often github.com/regclient/regclient is suggested as solution)

Comment: `regctl image copy docker/my-app:123 docker/my-app:latest` would work (from regclient), it will see the repository is the same and just do the minimal manifest pull/push.

Comment: I am going to solve this by pushing a new manifest with `docker manifest create  docker/my-app:latest --amend  docker/my-app:123-arm64 --amend  docker/my-app:123-amd64 && docker push docker/my-app:latest`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [buildx imagetools create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_imagetools_create/) command. A sample command would look like below:

```
docker buildx imagetools create -t docker/my-app:latest docker/my-app:123
```